# SSRS - How to get column value by column name

Tags: vba, reporting-services

I have one table with rows and each row has a column that contains a field name (say raw1 - 'Number001', raw2-'ShortChar003', etc). In order for me to get that value of these fields I have to use a second table; this table has 1 raw with many columns (number001, Number002, ShortChar003, etc).

How can I extract the value?

Comment: My understanding is that Lookup is used when you know the source and destination of the data you are looking for, but in this case I know the source, I don't know the destination as it is dynamic; what does Fields!CountColumn.Value does for me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Good Question..You can use lookup function

```
=Lookup(Fields!CityColumn.Value, Fields!CityColumn.Value, Fields!CountColumn.Value, "Dataset1")
```

Or you might have to use string functions..ex LEFT, Substring, Right same like SQL.If possible pls post some data of both tables, I will explain in detail